# Alternatives to using functools.partial with string methods

Tags: python, string, performance, arguments, partial

A profiling of my code shows that methods `split` and `strip` of `str` objects are amongst the the most called functions.

It happens that I use constructs such as:

```py
with open(filename, "r") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        fields = line.strip("\n").split("\t")
```

And some of the files to which this is applied have a lot of lines.

So I tried using the "avoid dots" advice in https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips as follows:

```py
from functools import partial
split = str.split
tabsplit = partial(split, "\t")
strip = str.strip
endlinestrip = partial(strip, "\n")
def get_fields(tab_sep_line):
    return tabsplit(endlinestrip(tab_sep_line))

with open(filename, "r") as my_file:
    for line in my_file:
        fields = getfields(line)
```

However, this gave me a `ValueError: empty separator` for the `return` line of my `get_fields` function.

After investigating, what I understand is that the separator for the `split` method is the second positional argument, the first being the string object itself, which made `functools.partial` understand `"\t"` as the string to be split, and I was using the result of `"\n".strip(tab_sep_line)` as separator. Hence the error.

What woud you suggest to do instead?

---

Edit:
I tried to compare three ways to implement the `get_fields` function.

Approach 1: Using plain `.strip` and `.split`

```py
def get_fields(tab_sep_line):
    return tab_sep_line.strip("\n").split("\t")
```

Approach 2: Using `lambda`

```py
split = str.split
strip = str.strip
tabsplit = lambda s : split(s, "\t")
endlinestrip = lambda s : strip(s, "\n")
def get_fields(tab_sep_line):
    return tabsplit(endlinestrip(tab_sep_line))
```

Approach 3: Using the answer provided by Jason S

```py
split = str.split
strip = str.strip
def get_fields(tab_sep_line):
    return split(strip(tab_sep_line, "\n"), "\t")
```

Profiling indicates cumulated time for `get_fields` as follows:

Approach 1: 13.027

Approach 2: 16.487

Approach 3: 9.714

So avoiding dots makes a difference but using `lambda` seems counter-productive.

Comment: If it's really important it's worth getting rid of `get_fields()` and just inlining the expression in the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The advice to "avoid dots" for performance is (1) only something you should do if you actually have a performance problem, i.e. not if it's just called a lot of times but if it actually *takes too much time*, and (2) not going to be solved by using `partial`.

The reason dots can take more time than locals is that python has to perform a lookup each time. But if you use `partial`, then there's an extra function call each time *and* it also copies and updates a dictionary each time *and* adds two lists. You're not gaining, you're losing.

However, if you really want you can do:

```
strip = str.strip
split = str.split
...
fields = split(strip(line), '\t')
```